# Define nested objects in flow types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

```js
export type TOption = {
  input_type: string,
  label: string,
  option_id: string,
  value: any
};

export type TOptions = {
  [key: string]: TOption
};
```

I am trying to define a Type that is an object that has a dynamic number of key-value pairs where each value is an object with input_type, label, option_id, value.

However, flow is throwing incompatible type error

```js
  Property `option_id` is incompatible:
     19:   [key: string]: TOption
                          ^^^^^^^ object type. This type is incompatible with
     14:   option_id: string,
                      ^^^^^^ string
```

I think I am defining it incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to define it. Can anyone point out the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The following code is working for dynamic nested types. If you are trying to achieve the same.

```
/* @flow */

type TOption = {
    input_type: string,
    label: string,
    option_id: string,
    value: any
}

type TOptions = {
    [key: string]: TOption
}

var myObj: TOptions = {
    data: {
        input_type: 'my_input_type',
        label: 'my_label',
        option_id: 'my_option_id',
        value: 12
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting. I have to look further then on why my version erroring out with flow